# How to put build cause data into build list on jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, build, gitlab

I have the following build list on my jenkins:

[image]

and the following build cause for e.g. build #40

[image]

How can I put this build cause "Started by Gitlab push by Patryk" into the build list? (underneath the approriate build)

I now this can be done since I had that running few days back but I cannot restore that behaviour. I am using https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin plugin for gitlab hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a wrong/old version of this plugin https://github.com/DABSquared/gitlab-plugin and I couldn't find the option in Jenkins to "show detailed build information".

Now in new version it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) , with [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin).
Set Build Name to `Started by ${ENV,var="BUILD_USER"}`